# Why is my character controller deacceleration not working?

Tags: unity, c#, movement

I want my player to deaccelerate when he stop not just stop in place.
Here is my code:

```
public override Vector3 Move(MovementManager manager, Vector2 input, bool jump, bool isCrouching)
{
    float speed = isCrouching ? CrouchSpeed : MoveSpeed;
    Vector3 velocity = manager.Velocity;

    float currentVelocity = new Vector3(velocity.x, 0, velocity.z).magnitude;
    Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;

    if (Mathf.Abs(input.x) > 0 || Mathf.Abs(input.y) > 0)
    {
        moveDirection = new Vector3(input.x, 0, input.y);
        moveDirection = manager.transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);

        if(input.y > 0)
        moveDirection *= input.y;

        LastMoveDirection = moveDirection;

        if (IsWalkSpeed) currentVelocity += (Acceleration * .4f) * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        else currentVelocity += Acceleration * Time.fixedDeltaTime;

        //if (currentVelocity > MaxSpeed) currentVelocity = MaxSpeed;
        if (currentVelocity > speed) currentVelocity = speed;
        return moveDirection.normalized * currentVelocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    }
    else
    {
        currentVelocity -= Deacceleration * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        currentVelocity = Mathf.Max(currentVelocity, 0);

        return LastMoveDirection.normalized * currentVelocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe `Deacceleration` is too large?

Comment: I changed it to a smaller value but it still doesn't work. When I log the Deacceleration it seams it doesn't get the right value it is smaller.

Comment: Maybe some radical modification should be done to locate the problem, how about setting the Deacceleration to 0? It expects results that don't slow down.

Comment: Setting it to zero does nothing.

Comment: Ok I think the Deacceleration is working but there is a problem with movedirection vector

Comment: Do you have any idea how can I fix movedirection vector

Comment: Is `manager.Velocity` set to a valid value? I noticed that if it's always a zero vector, the move function also works to some extent.

Comment: It should be it just gets current velocity. Even if I change the currentVelocity to initial value of 0 it still works the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136857/discussion-between-mangata-and-ivan).

Comment: I fixed it I will post a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
 public override Vector3 Move(MovementManager manager, Vector2 input, bool jump, bool isCrouching)
{
    float speed = isCrouching ? CrouchSpeed : MoveSpeed;
    Input = input;


    if (Mathf.Abs(input.x) > 0 || Mathf.Abs(input.y) > 0)
    {
        moveDirection = new Vector3(input.x, 0, input.y);
        moveDirection = manager.transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);

        if (input.y > 0)
            moveDirection *= input.y;

        LastMoveDirection = moveDirection;

        if (IsWalkSpeed) currentVelocity += (Acceleration * .4f) * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        else currentVelocity += Acceleration * Time.fixedDeltaTime;

        //if (currentVelocity > MaxSpeed) currentVelocity = MaxSpeed;
        if (currentVelocity > speed) currentVelocity = speed;

    }
    else if(input.x <= 0 && input.y <= 0)
    {
        currentVelocity -= Deacceleration * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        currentVelocity = Mathf.Max(currentVelocity, 0);
    }

    return LastMoveDirection.normalized * currentVelocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime;

}
```

There was the problem with moveDirection and manager.velocity these 2 vectors were zero at a specific point so the player just stop in place. Deacceleration was working but it was multiply by the zero vector  so it did nothing.